# How to pass array of strings as parameter to function?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, fasm

How can I pass array of strings as parameter to function in assembler?
For example lets say I want to call execve() function which looks like this:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

so I do this:

## test.asm

```
format elf executable

entry main

main:
    mov eax, 11 ; execve - executes program
    mov ebx, filename   ; label name is address of string variable
    mov ecx, args       ; label name is address of array of strings?
    mov edx, 0          ; NULL
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1  ;exit
    int 80h
    ret

filename db '/bin/ls', 0        ; path to program
args db '/bin/ls', 0, '.', 0, 0 ; array should end with empty string to
                                ; indicate end of array
```

## makefile

```
all:
    ~/apps/fasm/fasm ./test.asm
```

But when I run my program execve() fails to execute requested program and strace ./test shows this message:

```
execve("/bin/ls", [0x6e69622f, 0x736c2f, 0x2e], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

How to properly pass "args" variable to execve function?

Thanks :)

Comment: To find out how something is done, write it in C and look at compiler output.

Comment: Use `lea ebx, [ filename ]` to move the address of a label into a register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how this works in C? Strings are pointers, and a string array is an array of pointers. Thus you need to do something like:

```
filename db '/bin/ls', 0 
dot db '.', 0
args dd filename, dot, 0
```

Notice that `args` is `dd` to get pointer size items, and it is filled with the addresses of strings.